# Creating an Array from CSV file

Tags: powershell

In the below code I am try to group the `cateogry0` column by "Group" and matching the Excluded column to be `False`. Then I am taking the `Account0` and `Domain0` with the filtered out columns and making a new csv with just those two columns and imported data.

Ultimately it will look like the second image. I also am filtering out the same named columns in the `Account0` column.

I am trying to make a Multi-Dimensional Array named `$GroupName` and I want to use the code below to make the array.

How do I use the following code to create that Multi-dimensional array? Or, do you believe I should leave the code like this?

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\folder\Testnumberone.csv" | Where-Object {($_.category0 -eq "Group") -and ($_.Excluded -match "False")} | Select-Object "Account0", "Domain0" | sort Account0 -Unique

$csv | Export-Csv "C:\folder\TestOutput1.csv"-NoTypeInformation
```

[image: Image of importing csv document.]

[image: second image]

Comment: What is it that isn't working for you?

Comment: @JamesC. the code works, I was looking to do it a different way by making an Array called group name.

Comment: Where is the 3rd dimension with only 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\folder\Testnumberone.csv" | Where {($_.category0 -eq "Group") -and ($_.Excluded -match "False")} | group Account0 | %{[pscustomobject]@{BaseName=$_.Name;Name=$_.group.Domain0 -join ","}}
```